# translate_address in c++\linux

Tags: c++, linux, translation

i am trying to make user threads in C++, so while trying to initialize them i am getting a compiler error :translate_address was not declared in this scope

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <csignal>
#include <csetjmp>

#define JB_SP 6 //Location in the code
#define JB_PC 7 //Stack pointer
#define STACK_SIZE 10

typedef unsigned long address_t; //64bit address

sigjmp_buf jbuf[3];
char stack1[STACK_SIZE];

void f(){

}

void setup(){
    unsigned int sp, pc;
    sp = (address_t)stack1 + STACK_SIZE - sizeof(address_t);
    pc = (address_t)f;
    sigsetjmp(jbuf[0],1);
    (jbuf[0]->__jmpbuf)[JB_SP] = translate_address(sp);
    (jbuf[0]->__jmpbuf)[JB_PC] = translate_address(pc);
    sigemptyset(&jbuf[0]->__saved_mask);//empty saved signal mask

}


int main(){


    return 1;
}
```

am i meant to include it some how? or is there a different problem?

thank you.

Comment: Where is this "translate_address" supposed to come from?

Comment: what is translate_address??? Is it user defined function?

Comment: Can you provide some kind of reference to who or what provides `translate_address()`? I've never heard of this function before, `man -k translate_address` can't find it, and Google didn't provide anything on the first page of hits that looked like an even vaguely-common library routine.

Answer (score 1):

`translate_address` is not a Linux function. If you're referring to some kind of book or example code, it should explain where you're supposed to get this function from. If it doesn't, chances are it's not meant for Linux (or is a really, really bad reference/example).

Furthermore, you should NOT modify the contents of `jmp_buf` or `sigjmp_buf` directly. These are architecture and platform-dependent structures, and only the C library is allowed to mess with them. Since the contents of the structures are OS-dependent, if you're using a reference intended for some other OS when modifying `sigjmp_buf`, Bad Things will happen.

You should instead either use [`setcontext`, `getcontext`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setcontext), and [`makecontext`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/makecontext) for user threads (fibers) or  [`pthread_create`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) for OS-level threads.